# pixel image to tile map

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a game in pygame/python, and I am wondering who has the know how to show me to turn an image into a map.

The idea is simple. The image is colored by tile type. When the program loads the image, I want the color (example) #ff13ae to be matched to a certain grass tile, and the color (example) #ff13bd to a different tile. Now, I know that I may very well have to convert from hexcodes to rgb, but that is trivial. I just want to know the way I would go about this, mainly because all my other games don't do anything of this sort.

Comment: Possibly through surface.get_at((x,y))? http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at

Comment: That might be a bit slow, as it said. This map is pretty massive. It would look kind of bad it there was a really long load time. Does help though. I could use that for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pygame.PixelArray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html):

> The PixelArray wraps a Surface and provides direct access to the surface's pixels.
> [...]
>
> ```
> pxarray = pygame.PixelArray(surface)
> # Check, if the first pixel at the topleft corner is blue
> if pxarray[0, 0] == surface.map_rgb((0, 0, 255)):
>    ...
> ```